# 'command not found' after switching users on remote server

Tags: ubuntu, pyinstaller

I installed PyInstaller on my remote Ubuntu server logged in as user A, and added the installation location to my PATH, to access PyInstaller commands.
I'm able to use PyInstaller logged in as user A, but when I `sudo su` to user B, I get *-bash: pyinstaller: command not found*.

When I log out of the server and log in as user B, I'm able to use PyInstaller, but when I `sudo su` to user A, I get the same error. `sudo su`-ing back to user B, I still get that error.

Seems I only have access to PyInstaller with the user session I do my initial login with. Anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using su with -?

Comment: Yup, quite sure. Just su user